# Каков хороший дизайн (схема) базы данных для плана рабочего дня студента

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

На данный момент я создал такую схему https://dbdesigner.page.link/Qbt5snDBnmzYraKQA , так как я новичок в базах данных, я не знаю, хорошо ли спроектирована такая база данных или нет. Есть ли другой лучший подход к разработке такого рода базы данных? Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным и не требовать обращения к сторонним сайтам (ссылка может быть дополнением к вопросу, но не существенной его частью без которой вопрос не понять), так что включите диаграмму в виде снимка экрана в вопрос. По сути вопроса: хороша схема или нет, зависит от требований к системе, а мы их не знаем, значит не можем оценить, кроме как очевидные ляпы технического характера. В текущем виде (после добавления диаграммы) на вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: просмотреть хорошо ли использовали связи между таблицами, или целесообразны таблицы